# How to define built in function in "my" python interpreter?

Tags: python

I would like to add a python function in my interpreter that exists by default whenever I run python in my shell. The scenario I want is:

write a function like this once:

```
def clear():
  import os
  os.system('clear')
```

And run python in shell

Then I type `clear()` and the screen gets cleared without having to define clear each time I invoke python interpreter.

I am interested in a solution that fits Ubuntu or any Linux distribution. however, any solution for any platform is welcome.

Comment: thanks for your reply. is there a way that this personal library gets loaded by default whenever I start python?

Comment: If you just want clear, then why don't you use iPython interpreter instead of the default repl? Try it out. You will thank me later :)

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks a lot. you answered my question.

Comment: @BanachTarski though it is not just clear I want, but I will try it. thanks a lot ^_^

Comment: I'd actually say, if you're using python repl, and ipython, you might as well go big and go with an ipython/jupyter notebook

Comment: Voting to re-open. The duplicate does not answer the question. The question is not about ipython nor numpy.

Using User Customisation from https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/appendix.html#the-customization-modules is the generic way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Customisation Modules: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/appendix.html#the-customization-modules

With it, you can run code and define methods that are available when Python starts up interactively.

First, find where Python is looking for the user customisation directory is. Start `python` and type:

```
>>> import site
>>> site.getusersitepackages()
'/home/user/myuser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages'
```

The last string given is the customisation directory. If it does not exist, create it. Then create a file in your customisation directory called `usercustomize.py`. Add your code from the question to it. Save and restart Python.

Voila! You can now type:

```
>>> clear()
```