# How to add a function as a default function of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to add a clear screen function to the standard function list (without importing it) such as `print` on python. When I invoke `clear` in python it should clear the screen. How can I do it?

```
import os
def clear():
    os.system("clear")
    #os.system('echo -ne "\eD\eD\eD\e[A\e[A\e[A"')
```

Secondly any idea why [this is not working](https://superuser.com/a/1107093/118141) `os.system('echo -ne "\eD\eD\eD\e[A\e[A\e[A"')`

Edit:

Solution for `os.system('echo -ne "\eD\eD\eD\e[A\e[A\e[A"')` is `print('\x1b[J\x1b[A\x1b[A\x1b[A'*20, end='')`(py3) whole credit to this code goes to @metatoaster

Comment: You just import it?

Comment: Don't want to import it. I want it as standard function

Comment: Also using `os.system` to clear a screen is not cross-platform. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23980136/2904896

Comment: That's not how it should be done. How would an other developer looking at your code know where `clear` comes from and where it is documented?

Comment: Also, calling `os.system("echo` will not achieve what you want.  Just use the Python built-in print function to achieve what you want on posix: `print(chr(27) + "[2J")`

Comment: @KlausD. I want to use it locally same as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119983/how-to-define-built-in-function-in-my-python-interpreter

Comment: @metatoaster Its not about adding empty space but  to scroll up and down

Comment: @Eka you can't achieve that using echo from within Python, and use `print` and replace all `\e` with `chr(27)` much like how I indicated using the example.  Alternatively use `\x1b` instead, so you would replace that whole "not working" statement with `print('\x1b[2J\x1bD\x1bD\x1bD\x1b[A\x1b[A\x1b[A', end='')` to both clear screen and shift the lines as you indicated.

Comment: Hey thanks it worked in python3. Its adding empty space above the cursor any way to remove it and add below the cursor.

Comment: @metatoaster I found the solution thanks to your code `print('\x1b[J\x1b[A\x1b[A\x1b[A'*20, end='')` many thanks :)